# use findfirstfile and findnextfile to search in subdirectories

Tags: c++, file, directory

Pretty new here in the C++ world as I am more familiar with C#.  I managed to get findfirstfile and findnextfile to work but i'm wondering if there is a simple way of searching thru different drives or even just subdirectories.

Thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) and [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator)

Comment: You can use [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). and the likes of 'directory_iterator` or `recursive_directory_iterator` to do it pretty easily.

Comment: Can you give a code example please

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm running an older visual studios.  I believe those needs C++17

Comment: *Unfortunately, i'm running an older visual studios* -- You can use [boost filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to use std::filesystem, for example like this

```cpp
    std::string tasksFolderName = "/home/user";
    std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator fit(tasksFolderName);
    for (auto& f : fit) {
        if (std::experimental::filesystem::is_directory(f.path())) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto& p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(<Directory to iterate>))
    std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
```

You can use above code. To use this you need a compiler which supports c++17.
You can read more about [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which is introduced in c++17.

Hope this will help.